# Crear un dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

Hola estoy probando el siguiente codigo para obtener las provincias que presentaron más de 10 casos en fecha 2020-09-10, y tengo que guardar en un dataframe pero no estoy consiguiendo hacerlo. Necesito guardarlo en un dataframe para luego usar la libreria geoplotlib y mostrar esos resultados en un mapa
import pandas as pd
import geoplotlib

```
# Leemos de nuevo el DF
covid = pd.read_csv("provincias_covid19_datos_sanidad_nueva_serie.csv")

#provincias con mas de 10 casos en fecha 2020-09-10
p = covid.loc[covid['Fecha'] == '2020-09-10']
pr = p.loc[p['Casos'] > 10, 'provincia']


#mostramos en pantalla
print(pr)
```

Este es el archivo csv original sin modificacion

```
    Fecha   cod_ine provincia   Casos   Fallecidos  Hospitalizados  UCI
0   2020-01-01  0   No consta   0   0   0   0
1   2020-01-01  1   Araba/Álava 0   0   0   0
2   2020-01-01  2   Albacete    0   0   0   0
3   2020-01-01  3   Alicante/Alacant    0   0   0   0
4   2020-01-01  4   Almería 0   0   0   0
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
27555   2021-06-03  48  Bizkaia 0   0   0   0
27556   2021-06-03  49  Zamora  0   0   0   0
27557   2021-06-03  50  Zaragoza    0   0   0   0
27558   2021-06-03  51  Ceuta   4   0   0   0
27559   2021-06-03  52  Melilla 0   0   0   0
27560 rows × 7 columns
```

Comment: y cual es el resultado que esperas?, ademas intenta con esto `provincias_1 
 = covid[covid['Fecha'] == '2020-05-01']`

Comment: es que creo que no es correcto el resultado, si dejo el csv arriba

Comment: Ya esta añade todos los datos del .csv ya sumados y en texto gracias

Comment: ya esta puse el original también

Comment: ok ahora reviso el codigo y en un rato publico la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Hay 2 posibles soluciones, esto depende de como usaras los datos mas adelante. Voy a mostrar y explicar ambas.

primero construimos el DataFrame con los datos que has puesto (todos tienen 0 >_<).

```py
import pandas as pd

cols = ["Fecha","cod_ine","provincia","Casos","Fallecidos","Hospitalizados","UCI"]
data = [["2020-01-01",0,"No consta",11,0,0,0], #se modifico para la prueba
["2020-01-01",1,"Araba/Álava",20,0,0,0],
["2020-01-01",2,"Albacete",0,0,0,0],
["2020-01-01",3,"Alicante/Alacant",0,0,0,0],
["2020-01-01",4,"Almería",0,0,0,0],
["2021-06-03",48,"Bizkaia",0,0,0,0],
["2021-06-03",49,"Zamora",0,0,0,0],
["2021-06-03",50,"Zaragoza",0,0,0,0],
["2021-06-03",51,"Ceuta",4,0,0,0],
["2021-06-03",52,"Melilla",0,0,0,0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=cols)
```

**resultado**

|  | Fecha | cod_ine | provincia | Casos | Fallecidos | Hospitalizados | UCI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-01-01 | 0 | No consta | 11 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 1 | Araba/Álava | 20 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 | 2 | Albacete | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 2020-01-01 | 3 | Alicante/Alacant | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 2020-01-01 | 4 | Almería | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 2021-06-03 | 48 | Bizkaia | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | 2021-06-03 | 49 | Zamora | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 7 | 2021-06-03 | 50 | Zaragoza | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 8 | 2021-06-03 | 51 | Ceuta | 4 0 | 0 | 0 |  |
| 9 | 2021-06-03 | 52 | Melilla | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |

##### Agrupando datos (primera forma)

Para esto usaremos la función de pandas `groupby()` para agrupar los datos en base a algo y aquí podemos hacerlo de 2 forma.

**agrupando datos de una fecha seleccionada**

```
#escogemos los datos con una fecha
df = df[df["Fecha"]=="2020-01-01"]
#agrupamos segun su provincia y sumamos
df_group = df.groupby("provincia").sum()

#obtenemos los casos
casos = df_group[df_group["Casos"]>10]
print(casos)
```

**resultado**

|  | cod_ine | Casos | Fallecidos | Hospitalizados | UCI |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| provincia |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Araba/Álava | 1 | 20 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |
| No consta | 0 | 11 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |

**agrupando por fecha y provincia**

Para este caso le pasaremos una lista al método `groupby()` indicándole que agrupe por `Fecha` y `provincia` y luego haga la suma (que dará 0 por los datos)

|  |  | cod_ine | Casos | Fallecidos | Hospitalizados | UCI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fecha | provincia |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2020-01-01 | Albacete | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
|  | Alicante/Alacant | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
|  | Almería | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
|  | Araba/Álava | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
|  | No consta | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-06-03 | Bizkaia | 48 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
|  | Ceuta | 51 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
|  | Melilla | 52 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
|  | Zamora | 49 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
|  | Zaragoza | 50 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

En mi opinión considero que esta sería la forma mas cómoda y fácil de trabajar, pue si queremos una fecha en especifico podemos acceder a ella mediante `loc`

```py
df_group = df.groupby(["Fecha","provincia"]).sum()
fecha1 = df_group.loc["2020-01-01",:]
print(fecha1[fecha1["Casos"]>10])
```

**resultado**

| cod_ine | Casos | Fallecidos | Hospitalizados | UCI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| provincia |  |  |  |  |
| Araba/Álava | 1 | 20 | 0 | 0 |
| No consta | 0 | 11 | 0 | 0 |

De la misma forma podemos acceder a los `Casos` o  a los `Fallecidos` con `df_group["Casos"]`.

##### *Filtrando* datos (segunda forma)

Para esta forma solo haces una selección o *filtro* simple (esto don el df original)

```py
df_f = df[df["Fecha"]=="2020-01-01"]
#obtenemos los casos
df_casos = df_f[df_f["Casos"]>10]["provincia"]
print(df_casos)
```

**resultado**

> Lo siento por no ponerlo en una tabla (me demoro mucho armando la tabla)

```
0      No consta
1    Araba/Álava
Name: provincia, dtype: object
```

Comment: ya es que no puedes añadir manualmente todas las filas ya que son 27560

Comment: solo estoy replicando tu dataframe, ese es el resultado que tendras al hacer `df = pd.read_csv("provincias_covid19_datos_sanidad_nueva_serie.csv")`

Comment: Gracias , pero no resuelve mi duda ya que no  muestras las provincias que presentaron más de 10 casos en fecha

Comment: >_< lo siento me olvide de eso, ahora lo agrego

Comment: @Li_9 listo respuesta editada

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: si resolvió tu problema?

Comment: si, ya esta :) muchas gracias por toda la ayuda

Comment: Si la respuesta te ha sido útil, no olvide marcarla como aceptada y eventualmente votarla positivamente.

Comment: +10 porque es tremendamente frustrante resolver preguntas cuando ni siquiera colocan un dataframe de muestra, cuando es así, yo paso derecho... Aparte, resolviste la pregunta.